# React JSX syntax in REACT FINAL FORM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

From the example of a React library called REACT FINAL FORM at https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/Field. I've seen an example where the props property being used in `render()` function. I'm wondering how this possible

```
<Field name="myField">
  {props => (
    <div>
      <input {...props.input} />
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is called render props. you can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

in the mean time it's like this:

```
const Field = (props) => {
  //this is some data here
  // in the end you pass the data to childern like a function
  return props.children(/** HERE IS THE DATA YOU'RE GETTING FROM THAT PROPS WHICH CONFUSED YOU */)
}
```

```
<Field name="myField">
  {//THE DATA YOU PASS TO ABOVE CHILDREN YOU GET IT HERE
    props => (
    <div>
      <input {...props.input} />
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called Render Props. You can learn more from here

https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html